# How to use Webhooks in Python? (With PayPal)

Tags: python, paypal, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi I am working on a project that requires a bot to look at my PayPal business subscriptions every so often to see if any subscriptions have changed and then make the changers to my user's plans accordingly.  Basically I just need a method that, when called, returns all of the unhandled webhooks.I've seen that webhooks are able to do this (I think) but I have absolutely no experience working with them and I am kind of new to backend development.

Here is the link to PayPal documentation that may be useful: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/

And here are some examples in a GitHub that I found but I really don't know what to make of it:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/tree/master/samples/notification

I have been trying this for hours on end and I can't find a code solution that works for me. All I have is the Paypal developer credentials needed, and a webhook url and I don't know even where to start and what to do with that. I've gotten this far:

```
paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "sandbox",
  "client_id": os.getenv('PCID'),
  "client_secret": os.getenv('PCS'),
})
```

But after that I am lost. I appreciate all the help, Thanks :)

Comment: I think you might be confused about webhooks in general and how they work. You set up a page on your site that PayPal makes a request to with the webhook info, and you then process it. You don't write a script that checks them periodically because they're being sent and received and processed automatically -- this is the whole point of webhooks. They're like push notifications; you get them so you don't have to go look in an app to see if you got a text or not. I work at PayPal (for a few more days) but not on this product.

Comment: @agf Yeah I think that clarifies it. So is there any way to refactor what I said to make it work? Or is there a different way that you know of that could allow me to do what I want? Since I don't have a website and this is all run on a Python script I'm not sure exactly how I could make this work.

Comment: PayPal is generally meant to be used as part of a web site or app, so if that's not how you're using it, it'll likely be tougher to make things work. One option is to set up a site that just receives webhooks and puts them in a database somewhere for your script to process later. That's likely your best option. Another would be to not use webhooks at all and instead use some kind of search to get the subscriptions into your script, then check if / how they've changed yourself, instead of relying on the webhooks to tell you.

Comment: @agf Damn this is a tough situation. I mean is there anyway to just have like my computer run a server of some sort that spits out a url that PayPal can use, and then it just listens to webhooks on that URL and prints the data somewhere? The PayPal documentation is really not making this easy to learn and I have no clue where to even start......

Comment: Based on what you've said here, and in your other question, it sounds like a basic web app that receives webhooks and uses discord.py to post them to chat is what you want. That isn't a big project for someone who's written web apps in Python and used API libraries before, but it's definitely quite a bit to work through if you're still learning. Sorry I don't have a better answer for you. Maybe look for a local Python group in your area and see if they have any sort of project night or office hours or something.

Comment: @agf ok I appreciate the help. Ive used APIs before and am somewhat familiar with python, but usually the APIs have some sort of wrapper class that makes it easier and/or has at least decent documentation. Ill look in some other places, thanks.